# Serverless framework Cognito Userpool Pre Token Generator

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a PreTokenGenerator function which adds an additional claim to the id token.

In my serverless.yml I have the following definition.

```
functions:
  issueAuthToken:
    handler: src/handlers/cognitoPreToken.handler
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
        pool: ${self:provider.stage}-user-pool
        trigger: PreTokenGeneration
```

This runs and deploys, however does not wire up the user pool trigger in the userpool (see below)

[image]

How can I get this trigger to be setup? The documentation seems to be pretty lacking when it comes to cognito triggers

Answer (score 2):

Pre Token Generation is currently not available in the [UserPool LambdaConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-lambdaconfig.html) and hence [not supported by CloudFormation](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/571#issuecomment-350329553) (which serverless framework use). At the moment it can only be configured via console or AWS CLI.

Answer (score 2):

According to Serverless documentation, you should inform the attribute `existing: true` and this is very critical if you don't want to create a new Cognito User Pool [using-existing-pools](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cognito-user-pool/#using-existing-pools)

Also according to this forum this feature is now covered by AWS CloudFormation [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=268907)

This is a recent feature implemented by Serverless, so make sure you have the latest version installed.

Here is my Serverless configuration code:

```
preTokenGenerator:
    name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-preTokenGenerator
    description: Lambda service to list blog articles
    role: LambdaRole
    handler: functions/general/blog.list
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: my-pool-name
          trigger: PreTokenGeneration
          existing: true
```

I literally duplicated an existing function and changed its trigger.

[cognito-lambda-function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaZWJ.png)